# npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve. Angular 15

Tags: angular15

While installing new packages or while creating new applications in Angular 15.

I'm getting this error frequently.

npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/cdk@11.2.13
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@15.2.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^15.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=15.0.0" from @angular-architects/module-federation@15.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-architects/module-federation
npm ERR!     @angular-architects/module-federation@"^15.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (@angular-architects/module-federation-runtime, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@11.2.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^11.2.13" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@12.2.17
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@11.2.13
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^11.2.13" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

I tried the commands with --force and --legacy-peer-deps. But this is a temporary solution. I need a permanent solution.

Here goes my package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/elements": "^15.2.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.2.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.2",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^9.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^11.4.4",
    "streamsaver": "^2.0.5",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "@angular-architects/module-federation": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
}
```

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.2.5",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.17.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "jasmine": "^3.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.8.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^15.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
}
```

Comment: There is no permanent solution unless you are willing to put in the time to fix all the upstream dependency issues `--legacy-peer-deps` is something we're all stuck with for a while until common, but unmaintained, packages are gradually replaced by new options, and actively maintained projects all have their peerDependency conflicts resolved. If it's an annoyance, you could create an alias like `alias npmi='npm i --legacy-peer-deps`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `nodeJs` version, I am getting similar error with `Angular version 15` and noticed that my `NodeJs` was upgraded from `v 18` to `v 20.5.1`. I think downgrading `nodeJs to v 18` or upgrading `angular to version 17` will help resolve this error